# Glyph collision with package mathastext

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I was trying to type math in captions with a sans font when I came upon the `mathastext` package and I got greedier. I tested it with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[mdugm]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[subdued,defaultnormal,defaultrm,italic]{mathastext}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{biolinum-type1}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\Mathastext[biolinum]
\useosf% changes figure style in garamondx
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault

\newcommand{\testtext}{%
Distribution of singularities -- zeroes and poles -- for
the transfer function $A_v(f)$ in the $s$-domain according to $Q$.
\emph{Remark:} Observe that for $Q=1/2$, we have $p_0=\omega_0$. 
Testing oldstyle figures 0123456789.
\begin{equation}
 V_i(j\omega)=\frac{1}{2}
 \sum_n{}V_n\exp\{-j\phi_n\}\delta(j\omega\pm{}j\omega_n)\,,
\end{equation}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\MTVersion{normal}
\testtext
\par\MTVersion{biolinum}
\testtext
\end{document}
```

Almost everything works fine, but there are a couple of things I'd like to get fixed.

First, there are glyph collisions in math mode both in the roman font and in the sans font -- check the `(f` and the `(j`. The former does not occur when I do not resort to the `mathastext` package. Hence, I'd like to be able to use the package but either avoiding such collision or loading it only to have available a "sans math" mode. I haven't been able to load the packages in order for the math roman to be not affected by the `mathastext` package, though -- which, as I advanced, is interesting since the collisions do not occur when loading the `mathdesign`package without appending `mathastext`. Any help or suggestion about this issue?

Secondly, I'd like to avoid the glyph collision in the sans font. Is there a convenient way to avoid it without having to issue a command or a control sequence every time I'm going to type `(f` or `(j`?

Lastly, when using the sans font I get oldstyle figures even for math mode. Maybe this has to do with the `biolinum-type1` package, but how could I have text figures in text mode and lining figures in math mode?

Answer (score 1):

I can not test currently you MWE due to some font package problems, but recently [mathastext](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) has been updated with a new function `\MTsetmathskips`. So you could try to add in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\@tfor\@tempa:=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\do
    {\MTsetmathskips\@tempa{.5mu}{.5mu}}
\MTsetmathskips{j}{1.5mu}{.5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{f}{1.5mu}{.5mu}
\makeatother
```

This will space out the letters in (non-subdued) math mode. To be used sparingly... (currently also operator names like `exp` are spread out, I guess some option should be provided to not do that).